# Kivy text input time validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a Kivy project, and i'm having a hard time with **TextInput** property so my main gold is to have a text input with the following specifications :

1. Accept only numbers.
2. Set the length of text input to 5 caracteres.
3. insert colon **":"** automatically after the second number

to have the final result as this **10:45**

which is a valid time format, so if any one is able to do these three things at once i really need your help.

Comment: you could try something like `if len(your_textinput.text) == 2` add the colon using the `insert_text()` method, however the input filter of only numbers might stop you inserting a colon

Comment: or `if yourtextinput.get_curser_from_index() == (0,2)`

Comment: thanks brother, i'll go by your suggestion at worst case scenario

Comment: i'm not familiar with the property on the second comment, could you give me an example similar to my request